# the program is not able to find handler for MediatR query ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mediatr

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.2 and MediatR framework/library for query objects. When I run the program i face to this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Handler was not found for request of type
>   MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Store.Core.Queries.GetProductTypesQuery,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Store.Core.DomainModels.ProductType]].
>   Register your handlers with the container.

I added these packaged to my Store project (main project)

1- MediatR 7.0.0

2- MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

This is my **Startup.cs**

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
```

So this is my **Query** (located in a project called "Store.Core")

```
namespace Store.Core.Queries.Products
{
   public class GetProductTypesQuery : IRequest<IEnumerable<ProductType>> { }
}
```

This is my **QueryHandler** (located in another project called "Store.Data")

```
namespace Data.Queries.Products
{
    public class GetProductTypesQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetProductTypesQuery, IEnumerable<ProductType>>
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public GetProductTypesQueryHandler(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductType>> Handle(GetProductTypesQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _context.ProductType.OrderBy(p => p.ProductTypeID).ToListAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the Controller I used the MediatR

```
namespace Store.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        public HomeController(IMapper mapper, IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _mediator = mediator;   
        }


        public IActionResult Home() => View();

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Dishes(GetProductTypesQuery query) {
            var productTypes = await _mediator.Send(query);
            var productTypesViewModel = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductTypeVM>>(productTypes);
            return View(productTypesViewModel);
        }
}
}
```

my **ProductType** model (I Think it's not necessary but i added it in order to provide full info)

```
namespace Store.Core.DomainModels
{
    public class ProductType
    {
       public int ProductID { get; set; }
       public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The only part which is fishy for me is StartUp.cs (because I have queries and queries handlers in diffrent projects) but I don't know what i'm missing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As I guessed, the problem was the Startup.cs where u add the MediatR service. Since my Handlers were in separate assembly so we should mention that assembly name.
I changed this in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
}
```

To this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Data");
    services.AddMediatR(assembly);
}
```

Here "Data" is the name of my assembly where all Handlers are stored there.

Comment: In one of my projects I user like this `services.AddMediatR();` and works perfectly. Another project with exact configuration and NuGet packages I had to use as you show above. Thanks, it solved my problem but why would my other project works **without** the assembly input. All of them have the same namespaces in both projects.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to use:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(DeletePeopleCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
        services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    }
```

Here **`GetAssemblies()`** will load all handler classes.

Comment: I try this but it will not load handlers. instead i get assembly by name and it works : 
services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("Data"))

Answer (score 0):

I had this error.

Like a fool I had forgotten to make my handler implement `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>`, without which the container isn't looking for the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your handler is public.

Answer (score 0):

It also can be a problem if our RequestHandler in other csproj.

We have to find all these assemblies in startup, and register a proper way.